pandas.style.apply .to_excel is throwing keyerror
I have this df that has three columns A, B, C and I want to color the cell of B if A and B are equal. I also want to export it to excel with the style.
data = [[10, 30, 30], [15, 20, 33], [14, 40, 36]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

def highlight(df, color): 
    return np.where(df['A'] == df['B'], f"color: {color};", None)
df.style.apply(highlight, color='red', subset=['B']).to_excel(os.path.join(".\\data", 'highlighted_data.xlsx'), index=False)

But I get an error of this form:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 7
      5 def highlight_max(df, color): 
      6     return np.where(df['A'] == df['B'], f"color: {color};", None)
----> 7 df.style.apply(highlight_max, color='red', subset=['A']).to_excel(os.path.join(".\\data", 'highlighted_data.xlsx'), index=False)
      8 # df
      9 # ------------   ------------
     11 def highlight_pred(df, output_dir):

File d:\Apps\envs\cuda11\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py:537, in Styler.to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
    509 @doc(
    510     NDFrame.to_excel,
    511     klass="Styler",
   (...)
    533     storage_options: StorageOptions | None = None,
    534 ) -> None:
    535     from pandas.io.formats.excel import ExcelFormatter
--> 537     formatter = ExcelFormatter(
    538         self,
    539         na_rep=na_rep,
    540         cols=columns,
    541         header=header,
    542         float_format=float_format,
    543         index=index,
...
--> 417     raise KeyError(key)
    418 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    419 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'A'

And I have no idea what s going on.
I tried to set axis=1
df.style.apply(highlight, color='red', subset=['A'], axis=1).to_excel(os.path.join(".\\data", 'highlighted_data.xlsx'), index=False)

but with no success.

Check what df is inside highlight(). I have to check the docs to remember how it works, but I highly doubt it's actually a dataframe.

Confirmed, you need to specify axis=None for apply to pass in the entire df.

BTW, try to avoid shadowing names from outer scopes (df). Pylint can give you a warning about that: "Redefining name 'df' from outer scope (line 16) Pylint W0621:redefined-outer-name"

to_excel isn't actually relevant to the problem here, that's just when the styling gets evaluated. If you're using Jupyter, you can simply remove it and look at the styler directly in the notebook.

Secondly, subset=['B'] restricts the input to highlight to just the B column, so that's not what you want. BTW, the traceback and second snippet say subset=['A'].

Anyway, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. What do you want to ask exactly? Have you not done any debugging? Check out the [tour] if you haven't already, and for tips, see [ask].

Another thing: this data has no rows where A and B are equal, so not a good example.

I think I found a really elegant solution, so once you clarify what the question is, I'll post it.

It s exactly what the answer below tried to do!

Pardon? Which of my comments are you replying to?

You can use this:
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 2, 3], 'C': [7, 8, 9], 'D' : [7, 8, 9], 'E': [4, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

first_column_of_interest = 'A'
second_column_of_interest = 'B'

def highlight_max(s):
  # Only highlight second column of interest
  t = pd.Series('', index=s.index)
  if s[first_column_of_interest] == s[second_column_of_interest]:
    t[second_column_of_interest] = 'background-color: yellow'
  return t

#Writes to styled.xlsx
df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')


If columns C and D are of interest:
first_column_of_interest = 'C'
second_column_of_interest = 'D'



The parameter s is unused. There's got to be a better way to do this.

Updates response utilizes s

I don't think that's really an improvement. For one thing, if you add another column to df, this stops working.

The updated solution works for any number of columns as long as you want to compare the values of two columns and highlight the value in the latter column.

global index_1, index_2? You don't need to declare global just to access variables. You should remove that.

The new way is really convoluted. I prefer the original solution tbh. Like, why are you using globals instead of passing in arguments on **kwargs? And why are you using positional-style indexing when you could use the labels of a series? That is, something like t = pd.Series('', index=s.index); if s[index_1] == s[index_2]: t[index_2] = 'background-color: yellow'; return t

Thanks. I added your suggestion to the solution.

Oops, I wrote index_1 where I meant first_column_of_interest. Same for index_2.

I updated the solution with that change.
